# Putting one imagebutton and one button side by side on FrameLayout

Tags: android

I have a FrameLayout to show a Google Map, on the top left corner I have an ImageButton which throws an action. Now I need to put a Button on its right side. This is my layout as it is now, the button overlaps the ImageButton:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Empresas_Mapa" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_group_list_selector"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:onClick="openRuta"
        android:src="@drawable/navigator"
        android:text="Como llegar desde aquí... " />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnShowLocation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="openRuta"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/navigator"
            android:text="Ver mi posición actual " />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are several ways to achieve this

```
    <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnShowLocation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="openRuta"
                android:padding="4dp"
 android:paddingLeft="40dp"//this one is added
                    android:src="@drawable/navigator"
                    android:text="Ver mi posición actual " />
```

or you can try

```
<LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">


 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_group_list_selector"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:onClick="openRuta"
        android:src="@drawable/navigator"
        android:text="Como llegar desde aquí... " />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnShowLocation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="openRuta"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/navigator"
            android:text="Ver mi posición actual " />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Group `ImageButton` and `Button` using (wraping them in) `LinearLayout` ?

Comment: Thank you, your proposal is working, but the answer from Lat5t5arfighter is also fine.